# How to filter html from form data in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, escaping, silex

I'm pretty new to Silex and Symfony and I'm trying to create a form with the symfony Form component. That's working fine, but whet it comes to validation/sanitization I'm not sure how to do it.

Of course I know the $app->escape($data) method, but it doesn't seem to fit my needs.

I'd like to escape html tags from the submitted data before I call the $form->isValid() method. I don't want to invalidate texts with html tags, only escape/remove them from the text then validate the gained values.

So basically I want to give the escaped values to the form instead of the originals or use.

My problem is that I'd like to show the error messages only if the submitted text is empty after removing the html tags.

I thought about to write a custom constraint - as I didn't find anything about html validation in the package - but in that case I had to filter/escape two times, first in the validation then before saving the data.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {            
  $comment = $request->get('comment');
  if($comment) {
    foreach($comment as &$value) {
      $value = $app->escape($value);
    }

    $cleared = new Request(array(), array('comment' => $comment));

    $form->bindRequest($cleared);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      var_dump($form->getData());
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$app->escape()](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#escaping) is just a shortcut for [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), you have to use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function to remove html tags.

> My problem is that I'd like to show the error messages only if the
>   submitted text is empty after removing the html tags.

```
$form->get('FILED_NAME')->addError(new Form\FormError('ERROR'));
```

for example :

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {            
  $comment = $request->get('comment');
  if($comment) {
    $emptyCM = false;
    foreach($comment as &$value) {
      $value = strip_tags($value);
      if (empty($value)) $emptyCM = true;
    }
    if ($emptyCM) 
      $form->get('comment')->addError(new Form\FormError('my custom error message'));

    $cleared = new Request(array(), array('comment' => $comment));

    $form->bindRequest($cleared);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      var_dump($form->getData());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping that there's a built-in support for filtering the input. Something like a constraint but that should clear up the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pre-sanitize your all your data before it goes into the form, you can use a `before` filter, either for all routes or for specific routes.

The following example strips all tags from string parameters from GET and POST. If your parameters are arrays (like in your initial example), you'd need to add another `if` branch. If your parameters are deeply nested, you need a recursive function for filtering.

```
$app->before( function( Request $request ) {
    foreach ( [ $request->request, $request->query ] as $parameterBag ) {
        foreach ( $parameterBag->keys() as $key ) {
            if ( is_string( $parameterBag->get( $key ) ) ) {
                $parameterBag->set( $key, strip_tags( $parameterBag->get( $key ) ) );
            }
        }
    }
}, Application::EARLY_EVENT );
```